# i just cant make this code to work

Tags: jsp

i want to update my database via HTML but i dun know what is wrong. please guide me. i cannot execute this code. please help. i'm using button to trigger the query. but it doesn't show any error. i dont know what is wrong. out of clue.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>

<form name="edit" action="post">
<%
    String CustomerID = request.getParameter("CustomerID");
    String CustomerFirstName = request.getParameter("CustomerFirstName");
    String CustomerLastName = request.getParameter("CustomerLastName");
    String CustomerDOB = request.getParameter("CustomerDOB");
    String CustomerContact = request.getParameter("CustomerContact");
    String CustomerAddress = request.getParameter("CustomerAddress");
    String CustomerEmail = request.getParameter("CustomerEmail");

    try{
        if (request.getParameter("edit") != null) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basedinventorysystem",
                    "root", "onetwothree123");

            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            String command = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0";
            statement.executeUpdate(command);

            command = "UPDATE customertable SET CustomerID=?, CustomerFirstName=?, CustomerLastName=?, CustomerDOB=?, CustomerContact=?, CustomerAddress=?, CustomerEmail=? WHERE CustomerID=?";

            command.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(CustomerID));
            command.setString(2, CustomerFirstName);
            command.setString(3, CustomerLastName);
            command.setString(4, CustomerDOB);
            command.setString(5, CustomerContact);
            command.setString(6, CustomerAddress);
            command.setString(7, CustomerEmail);
            command.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(CustomerID));
            statement.executeUpdate(command);

            ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from customertable");

            while (resultset.next()) {
                out.print("Successfully Inserted");
                        }
                    }
%>
</form>
```

what is wrong w my code. can someone help me.

Comment: you cant execute means it shows an error, else it is executed but without the desired results

Comment: You have a try without catch or finally. That doesn't even compile. That code should be in a Java class, not in a JSP. There are many other errors. A String, for example, doesn't have any setInt() or setString() method.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried another approach and it work. and now i'm stuck on how do i wanna do codes on Stock increasing. i was given a status where when a stock was labeled as "ordered" the current stock qty still be the same and when the labeled change to "delivered" the stock will be automatically increased. I'm using Eclipse as platform on creating a .jsp file, tomcat server and MySql. so i'm hoping if there's any input on how i should start doing it.

anyway this are the code that i have tweak and it worked.

```
 <%
                if (request.getParameter("edit") !=null){
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basedinventorysystem",
                            "root", "onetwothree123");

                    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                    String command = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0";
                    statement.executeUpdate(command);

                    command = "UPDATE customertable SET CustomerID='"+Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("CustomerID"))
                    +"', CustomerFirstName='"+request.getParameter("CustomerFirstName")
                    +"', CustomerLastName='"+request.getParameter("CustomerLastName")
                    +"', CustomerDOB='"+request.getParameter("CustomerDOB")
                    +"', CustomerContact='"+request.getParameter("CustomerContact")
                    +"', CustomerAddress='"+request.getParameter("CustomerAdd")
                    +"', CustomerEmail='"+request.getParameter("CustomerEmail")
                    +"' WHERE CustomerID='"+Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("CustomerID"))+"';";

                    statement.executeUpdate(command);

                    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from customertable");

                    if (resultset.next()) {
                        out.println("Successfully Inserted");
                    }
                }

                %>
```